# LswApiCallerBundle POST data

Tags: symfony, curl

I want to make a call to this API: https://api.airbnb.com/v2/search_results, using Symfony2 and LswApiCallerBundle.

Following the instructions I make the call using this code:

```
$url = 'https://api.airbnb.com/v2/search_results';

$data = [
    'client_id' => '3092nxybyb0otqw18e8nh5nty',
];

$output = $this->get('api_caller')->call(new HttpGetJson($url, $data));
```

As a result I get this:

> Status: 0 Connection failed URL:
>   https://api.airbnb.com/v2/search_results Type:
>   Lsw\ApiCallerBundle\Call\HttpGetJson Request: 35 bytes raw html parsed
>   Response: 0 bytes raw html parsed  Time: 62.89 ms

With a "null" response. Can someone tell me please where I'm failing or if there is another way of doing it?

Thanks

Comment: check the response headers... idk how to do that in symfony2, but in curl, the best way is to enable CURLOPT_VERBOSE and CURLOPT_STDERR

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, substituting Lsw Bundle for Guzzle one(https://github.com/LeaseWeb/LswGuzzleBundle).
Follow the documentation to configure it.

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! Please insert the actual solution in the post as an answer instead of posting links. They can easily become unusable if the URL changes. Thanks